# Change CSS with Javascript but using Variables

Tags: javascript, css

I know this:

`document.getElemntById('object').style.height='50px';`

But instead of `'50'` (string), I want to use another variable (for Example `number`).

I wanted to do this because I want random numbers.

Any easy way to do it?

Comment: You want to set random height for the element? You can just replace the static
document.getElemntById('object').style.height=variable;

Comment: Just use a variable in place of the string and append 'px' on the end.

Comment: `.style.height = myvar + 'px'` <- it's pretty darn straight forward.

Comment: You also have a typo in your JS. `Elemnt` should be `Element`

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
var foobar = 25;
document.getElementById('object').style.height=foobar + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it with a random number between 1 and 100.  [Read more about Random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
var RandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1).toString();
document.getElementById('object').style.height=RandomNumber + 'px';
```

Comment: @dippas, why did you delete my link?

Comment: please don't refer to W3schools. See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @dippas I don't agree with your edit but I don't seem to have any power to undo the change. "W3fools" really did not explain why not to use W3Schools and as this question was a very basic one, I would again suggest to OP to check out W3Schools. `W3Fools: "...so when you're ready to level up, move on." `

Comment: @dippas Okay. Please check out that page and read the comments on the question yourself. You will discover that `w3fools` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable anywhere you can use a string literal.

```
var foo = "50px";
document.getElementById('object').style.height = foo;
```

Comment: He want a random numder, not a variable string

Comment: @AmadouBeye — The question is about using a variable instead of a string literal. They aren't asking how to put a random number in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random() * 300` to get a random from 1-300 float number, then `parseInt` to get a integer.

int + string will get you string in JS so no need to convert, just use `randompx + 'px'`

```js
var randompx = parseInt(Math.random() * 300) + 1;

//document.getElementById('object').style.height=randompx + 'px';

console.log(randompx+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random number like this and set the height. In the below example maxHeight is exclusive.

```
var minHeight = 10;
var maxHeight = 20;
var randomHeight = Math.floor((Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight)) + minHeight);

document.getElemntById('object').style.height = randomHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
document.getElemntById('object').style.height= randomNumber + 'px';
```

Comment: Re edit: Putting a string literal on the right hand side of the `+` operator will implicitly convert the LHS to a string. Calling the `toString()` function explicitly is pointless.